# Am I using find_or_create_by method properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design

I am trying to populate a new table from an existing database but my method does not seem to be working properly. Below is my code.

```
class CreateEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :employees do |t|
    t.string :first_name, null: false
    t.string :last_name, null: false
    t.string :email, null: false
    t.timestamps
  end
  Sale.find_each do |sale|
    unless Employee.exists?(sale.employee)
      puts "Employee #{sale.employee} created!"
    else
      puts "Employee #{sale.employee} already existed!"
    end
    employee_info = sale.employee.split
    Employee.find_or_create_by(first_name: employee_info[0],  last_name: employee_info[1], email:employee_info[2])
  end
end
end
```

What I have is a main database called sales that with a field that contains employee. In that field you will find a string entry as so: "Mary Higgins higgins@korning.com".
Basically the sales database contains four distinct employees but the employees are listed many times. What I'm trying to do is to create four unique rows. I thought the code above would work but something seems to be off with my logic. When I run the above code it, goes through the n amount of rows and creates the Employee object so, essentially the unless statement never results to true for some reason. Could the problem lie in the .find_each method. Would a .each suffice?  I don't know if any more information would need to be provided with my database but if its needed I'll supply more details.

Comment: What error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sale.employee is a string eg "Mary Higgins higgins@korning.com"

exists? excepts a hash with the conditions like Employee.exists?(:email => "higgins@korning.com"). If you pass a string like you did, first, it converts the string to an integer then tries to find the record with that id which in your case will be 0 and because of that it always returns false.

I would change the find_each loop like this:

```
 Sale.find_each do |sale|
    employee_info = sale.employee.split
    employee = Employee.find_or_create_by(first_name: employee_info[0],  last_name: employee_info[1], email:employee_info[2])
    if employee.new_record?
      puts "Employee #{sale.employee} created!"
    else
      puts "Employee #{sale.employee} already existed!"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rails Fan, it turns out that Employee.find_or_create_by and the unless logic accomplished the same task, which is why I ran into problems.